# Node TLS Ticket Reestablish Connection

Tags: node.js, session, ssl

I am doing experimenting in nodejs.  I'm trying to use a TLS Ticket to resume a TLS Session.  So I will make a client save off the TLS Ticket after successful connection.  After shut down I would like it to use the same TLS ticket to reestablish the TLS connection.

I have found the node tls command `tlsSocket.getTLSTicket()` however I am not sure how to use it to reestablish a connection because it's "Useful only for debugging".

What i want is the ability to get the TLSTicket from the client and manually validate it against a TLSTicketKey in a server in nodejs.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After spending way more time than I should have, these are what I found:

1. There doesn't seem to be any API or exposed JavaScript functions that would allow you to validate TLSTickets.

> Reusing sessions via session tickets works out-of-the box, the implementation is completely transparent for your node.js

https://strongloop.com/strongblog/improve-the-performance-of-the-node-js-https-server/

However, as you will see in the link, it is possible to manually handle sessions with a session store (which obviously defeats the purpose of TLS tickets).

2. Node uses the following function provided by OpenSSL to do Ticket processing.

   > SSL_CTX_set_tlsext_ticket_key_cb - set a callback for session ticket processing

Full Details: https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/d13d7f74d794340ac5e126cfb4ce507fe0f803d5/deps/openssl/openssl/doc/ssl/SSL_CTX_set_tlsext_ticket_key_cb.pod

It's done from here: https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/src/node_crypto.cc

3. Node does not emit `resumeSession` when it receives valid TLS ticket.
   The following GitHub issue describes why and is an easy reference to Node's TLS ticket implementation details.

https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/5872

Comment: Thanks, before I accept, I'm going to look through myself https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/src/node_crypto.cc.  I'm still hopeful it might be exposed through some js hacking.

Comment: The `getTicketKeys` and `setTicketKeys` are probably the functions you are looking for. However, I can't seem to find a place where they are being called. From openssl docs for set keys, `The callback function cb will be called for every client instigated TLS session when session ticket extension is presented in the TLS hello message. It is the responsibility of this function to create or retrieve the cryptographic parameters and to maintain their state.` However, I can't find how or where it's done.

Comment: Let me know of what you find and how you end up implementing this. Maybe, if you could get in touch with Fedor Indutny, you will get the most detailed explanation.

Comment: I suspect that the callback is being called in SecureContext::Init.  So my hope is that it may be possible in constructing a SecureContext in https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/_tls_common.js and checking state afterwards.

Comment: Ok so Openssl is a monster C++ codebase it's hard to find where anything happens.  Now I'm wondering if there is another javascript/node codebase that simply has a function which takes TLSTicket and TLSKey and returns True if Valid or False if not and returns Session Key.  I'm looking at forge: https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge.